# Django getting object which is just created, but returns nothing

Tags: django

I have a view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.is_ajax():
            try:
                post = Post.objects.all().last()
            except:
                return JsonResponse({'res': 0})
            print('got post: ' + str(post))
            try:
                post_chat_create = PostChat.objects.create(post=post, kind=POSTCHAT_TEXT, before=None, you_say=True, uuid=uuid.uuid4().hex)
                print('post chat has been created')
            except Exception as e:
                print('if it has exception: ' + str(e))
            print('just created post chat: ' + str(post_chat_create.pk))

            try:
                post_chat_last = PostChat.objects.all().last()
                print('any made post chat?: ' + str(post_chat_last))

            except PostChat.DoesNotExist:
                print('has error on getting post_chat_last')
            print('has no error on getting post_chat_last')
```

I think it is very weird because it prints something like it:

**print on terminal:**

got post: Post pk: 2, user: useruser1

post chat has been created

just created post chat: 32

any made post chat?: postchat: None

has no error on getting post_chat_last

**Question:**
Why? for sure, there was a creating of PostChat object. Because of this terminal line:`just created post chat: 32`

but `print('any made post chat?: ' + str(post_chat_last))` this line returns: 
`any made post chat?: postchat: None`

It's strange.

Just been made some PostChat, but can't get it.

Why this happened?

Here's models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    has_another_profile = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_open = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=34, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4().hex)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class PostChat(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    you_say = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    before = models.ForeignKey("PostChat", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    kind = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=KINDS_CHOICES, default=0)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=34, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4().hex)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Would you mind delete all `.pyc` files if you have and try `PostChat.objects.last()` instead. Can you also try to call `PostChat.objects.count()` before and after the creation? Also try `print('any made post chat?: ', post_chat_last)` to see if it is really None or str returns None and maybe start with this first.

Comment: Did you check the DB through *Django Admin*?

Comment: @Jerin Peter George Yes, checked DB and finally it is solved.

Comment: @touchingtwist what was the issue?

Comment: @AhmedHosny As you said, `PostChat.objects.last()` works. not `PostChat.objects.all().last()`. But I don't know what was the exact problem. Anyway, it solved.